# Not able to format in jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Can someone help me to get my code block (by prettify plugin) and headline seperated? I googled a lot but didn't find solution.
I have written a blog in jekyll and used prettify plugin to highlight code. Below configuration is there in my config.yml file

markdown: kramdown
highlighter: pygments
redcarpet:
  extensions: ["no_intra_emphasis", "fenced_code_blocks", "autolink", "tables",     "with_toc_data"]

kramdown:
  input:          GFM
  use_coderay:    true
  auto_ids:       true
  footnote_nr:    1
  entity_output:  as_char
  toc_levels:     1..6
  smart_quotes:   lsquo,rsquo,ldquo,rdquo
  enable_coderay: false

I am not able to post my image so please check the below URL for my  .md file snippet
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHroW.png

I expect headlines to be out of code block but
Below is the output of my blog https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEqVE.png

Comment: Please post your relevant .md file snippet as code and not a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight code in jekyll, this is useless to try a two years old plugin.

Just use [hightlight tag](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting) :

```
{% highlight java %}
import java.toto;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String fileContents = readEntireFile("./foo.txt");
    }

... many more java code here

}
{% endhighlight %}
```

You will also need a style sheet. One can be found [here](https://github.com/mojombo/tpw/blob/master/css/syntax.css) and some more examples [here](http://help.farbox.com/pygments.html).

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not really clear. Can you edit and explain the input and the output by pasting your code and not images.

Comment: My input was  

{% highlight java %}  
dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");  
......  
{% endhighlight %}  


## Dirty read, Phantom Read and Non Repeatable Read  


* **Dirty read** occurs .......

And the output I am seeing is as given in the following URL: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/11231867/8395343/a75b14de-1d88-11e5-8aaf-7f141de07858.PNG 

Please note that the java code is looking like plain text. Keywords are not getting highlighted